# Abstract not showing up, even when using \maketitle

Tags: errors, formatting, abstract, report

I'm using the `amsart` document class and have the following packages:

```
\documentclass[a4]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{verbatim,ifthen}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\def\heading#1{\centerline{\bf #1 }\vskip 10pt}
\newcommand\nextpage{\vfill\eject}

\addtolength{\textwidth}{80pt}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-40pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\begin{document}
\heading{Heading One} 

\heading{Heading Two}


\begin{abstract}
Here is an abstract
\end{abstract}
```

Even when I use the `\maketitle`, which is what many on here have suggested, I get an error saying that `\maketitle` was not defined. I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 8):

You need to define the components associated with a title in order to properly use `\maketitle`. Once that's done, the `abstract` will set with the rest of the title components:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\title[Short title]{A long title}
\author{An author}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Here is an abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```